# Joined elements should *all* match some criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division, sql-match-all

I have a setup like:

```
conversations(id) 

notifications(id, conversation_id, user_id)

users(id)
```

If a conversation concerns someone, the `user` is linked to the `conversation` through one `notification`.

GOAL: I'm looking for `conversations` which concern **exclusively** `users` with given ids.

---

The obvious:

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversations.* 
FROM "conversations" 
INNER JOIN "notifications" ON "notifications"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id"
WHERE notifications.user_id IN (1, 2)
```

doesn't work because it would also retrieve a conversation concerning:

- users with id 1, 2 and 3
- users with id 1 and 4
- users with id 2 and 4

and this is not desired.

Comment: Can you clearly know what do you need? Or give some sample output you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that each user can only be joined *once* to a conversation:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   conversations c
JOIN   notifications n1 ON n1.conversation_id = c.id
JOIN   notifications n2 ON n2.conversation_id = c.id
WHERE  n1.user_id = 1
AND    n2.user_id = 2
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   notifications n3
   WHERE  n3.conversation_id = c.id
   AND    n3.user_id <> ALL ('{1,2}')
  )
```

This is a special case of relational division. We have assembled a whole arsenal of techniques under this this related question:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

The special requirement is to exclude additional matches. I use `NOT EXISTS` for this end. You could also use `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT IN`. More details here:
[Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

#### There could be several notifications for the same user

To avoid duplicate conversations in the result you can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in addition to the above. Or you suppress duplicates to begin with (probably faster):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   conversations c
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   notifications n1
   JOIN   notifications n2 USING (conversation_id)
   WHERE  n1.conversation_id = c.id
   AND    n1.user_id = 1
   AND    n2.user_id = 2
  )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   notifications n3
   WHERE  n3.conversation_id = c.id
   AND    n3.user_id <> ALL ('{1,2}')
  )
```

Comment: There could be several notifications for the same user, does it break your condition?

Comment: @apneadiving: It does not completely break it, but you might get multiple rows per conversation. Can be amended easily ...

Comment: Looks great, cant test now unfortunately. Btw, quick answer for a 93 years old :)

Comment: Old one can be, but still quick, young padawan, if the force is strong with you. ;)

Comment: what book would you recommend for postgresql please?

Comment: @apneadiving: I have read a few, but that's decades ago. Remember, 93! Nowadays, I read the [excellent manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html) mostly (strong recommendation), the [Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Main_Page), the Postgres mailing lists and selected blog pages like [the one by Depesz](http://www.depesz.com/). And, well, Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversations.* 
FROM conversations c
    JOIN notifications n1 ON n1.conversation_id = c.id
    JOIN notifications n2 ON n2.conversation_id = n1.conversation_id AND n1.id <> n2.id
WHERE n1.user_id = 1 AND n2.User_Id =2
```

I think the question asks for conversations between User_Id = 1 and User_Id = 2...
If nobody other than 1 and 2 should be part of the conversation, then Eric's answer is what you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting code, put 4 spaces at the start of each line so it looks like code and not prose.

Comment: yes nobody else should be part of the conversation, +1 as welcome to stackoverflow